# How do i remove email header in Android

Tags: android

When I am forwarding or replying to an email that has included headers, I want to remove the header text. Also, how can I change the "from" address using the `setFrom()` method, such that the recipient will not see my email address. I want to make the "from" address be: `Do Not Reply <no-reply@domain.com>`.

Here is my code:

```
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(
                body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));

        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("Do Not Reply" + "<"
                + "no-reply@domain.com" + ">"));

        Address replyTo[] = { new InternetAddress("no-reply@domain.com") };
        message.setReplyTo(replyTo);

        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setDataHandler(handler);

        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
        else
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(recipients));
        Transport.send(message);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fixed some minor typos and grammatical errors. Removed redundant comment lines from the code example to make the question clearer.